# how to transform a python code to a gui using pyqt5? (using qt designer or other app are prohibited, i have to code it my self)

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, coding-style, pyqt5

i have written a simple code in python and i want to make a gui for it and i want to use pyqt5.
how can i make my code into a gui using pyqt5?
had no ideas how and where to start...
is there any good source to learn pyqt5 from the scratch for free?

this is my code by the way:

import random
def restart():
    return GuessingGame()

def GuessingGame():
    numbers= random.sample(range(9),5)

```
print("instruction:")
print("Correct = C, Wrong= W, Missplaced = M")
print("there are no repeative digits.")


lst=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

while (lst[0] != numbers[0] or lst[1] != numbers[1] or lst[2] != numbers[2] or lst[3] != numbers[3] or lst[4] != numbers[4]):

    g = int(input("Guess the five digit number:"))
    lst = [int(y) for y in str(g)]
    showcase = str()

    if (lst[0] == numbers[1] or lst[0] == numbers[2] or lst[0] == numbers[3] or lst[0] == numbers[4]):
        showcase= showcase + str("M,")
    elif (lst[0] != numbers[0] and lst[0] != numbers[1] and lst[0] != numbers[2] and lst[0] != numbers[3] and lst[0] != numbers[4]):
        showcase = showcase + str("W,")
    else:
        showcase = showcase + str("C,")

    if (lst[1] == numbers[0] or lst[1] == numbers[2] or lst[1] == numbers[3] or lst[1] == numbers[4]):
        showcase = showcase + str("M,")
    elif (lst[1] != numbers[0] and lst[1] != numbers[1] and lst[1] != numbers[2] and lst[1] != numbers[3] and lst[1] != numbers[4]):
        showcase = showcase + str("W,")
    else:
        showcase = showcase + str("C,")

    if (lst[2] == numbers[0] or lst[2] == numbers[1] or lst[2] == numbers[3] or lst[2] == numbers[4]):
        showcase = showcase + str("M,")
    elif (lst[2] != numbers[0] and lst[2] != numbers[1] and lst[2] != numbers[2] and lst[2] != numbers[3] and lst[2] != numbers[4]):
        showcase = showcase + str("W,")
    else:
        showcase = showcase + str("C,")

    if (lst[3] == numbers[0] or lst[3] == numbers[1] or lst[3] == numbers[2] or lst[3] == numbers[4]):
        showcase = showcase + str("M,")
    elif (lst[3] != numbers[0] and lst[3] != numbers[1] and lst[3] != numbers[2] and lst[3] != numbers[3] and lst[3] != numbers[4]):
        showcase = showcase + str("W,")
    else:showcase = showcase + str("C,")

    if lst[4] == numbers[0] or lst[4] == numbers[1] or lst[4] == numbers[2] or lst[4] == numbers[3]:
        showcase = showcase + str("M,")
    elif (lst[4] != numbers[0] and lst[4] != numbers[1] and lst[4] != numbers[2] and lst[4] != numbers[3] and lst[4] != numbers[4]):
        showcase = showcase + str("W,")
    else:
        showcase = showcase + str("C,")


    print("Status is:(",showcase,")")

if (lst[0] == numbers[0] and lst[1] == numbers[1] and lst[2] == numbers[2] and lst[3] == numbers[3] and lst[4] == numbers[4]):
    print("Winner Winner chiken dinner")
```

GuessingGame()

Comment: the first two lines(import random etc...) and the last one(guessing Game) out of the box are also in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can begin by using qt designer to generate GUI and then include your code in it.

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

Comment: thanks sir, actually the task is to create the GUI just by coding it, that how the principle wants it to be so using  qt designer is somehow prohibited. i shall edit my the topic of the question, i didn't mentioned this prohibition here.  thanks a lot by the way.